# ImageMagick batch convert images

Tags: command-line, 17.04, imagemagick

I'm working from a code from [wavexx - Facedetect](https://github.com/wavexx/facedetect).

There is an example for finding faces and converting them to a new file.

I've managed to get the example to work. But, I'm unable to find out how to read multiple images and batch process a whole folder with images.

I've tried the following to make this possible but it didn't work, though I found a page where they did something similar to achieve this.(using the * as a implementation for reading all files)

```
python facedetect
for file in folder/*.jpg; do
  name=$(basename "$file")
  i=0
  facedetect "$file" | while read x y w h; do
    convert "$file" -crop ${w}x${h}+${x}+${y} "folder2/${name%.*}_${i}.${name##*.}"
    i=$(($i+1))
  done
done
```

The error I got in the console was the following.

```
facedetect: error: cannot load input image folder/*.jpg
```

Though there is are files called 0001.jpg - 2786.jpg

I've only been running the unix grounds for a short time and even shorter when it comes to imagemagick.

1. Could use a page where batch processing images is explained.
2. kindly explain me what I did wrong and where to search for the solution or how to fix it.

the *.jpeg in my opinion should look at all .jpeg files in that folder, not?

Comment: The error message suggests that there were no files matching the glob expression `folder/*.jpg`, so that the shell passed it literally to the `facedetect` program (instead of passing a list of matching files). Check the path and retry.

Comment: Ok, indeed giving it the global path seemed to do the trick... 
I thought I'd tried that already, better triple check next time..